# Customize Bootstrap Navbar dropdown destroying the design when screen is small

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Well, I have this JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uvkt8z7j/16/ whenever the screen is small and I tried clicking the dropdown on the right, it seems to destroy the entire design. I would like have the same behavior when the screen is lrg while its on

```
  <body style="background-color: black;">
    <div id='header'>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <ul class='navbar-nav'>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- <div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div> -->
                            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/24/black/dining-room-filled.png">
                    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE ORDER ONLINE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE INFO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE LOCATORS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>`
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the bootstrap class (in smaller screens) to fix this issue.
See the media query in the demo below:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 992px){
    #header .dropdown-menu{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body style="background-color: black;">
    <div id='header'>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

        <ul class='navbar-nav'>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <!-- <div>Icons made by <a href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div> -->
                            <img src="https://png.icons8.com/ios/24/black/dining-room-filled.png">
                    </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE ORDER ONLINE <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE INFO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link menu-selection" href="#">STORE LOCATORS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
```